# How to improve the Xpath using the regular expression

Tags: regex, selenium, xpath

I am using `SeleniumWebdriver` to identify the elements and in one of the instance, I have defined one of the xPath as mentione below.

```
//div[contains(@id,'confirm1_container') or contains
(@id,'confirm2_container') or contains(@id,'confirm3_container') or contains
(@id,'confirm4_container')or contains
(@id,'permanentSuppressionPopUp_container')]
```

The reason for this, it should pass one of them and identify the element.

The question here, Is there a easy way or any suggestion to improve this xpath instead of having multiple OR operators.If you see theid's only change is the "number" in between confirm and _container.

I did go through old suggestion but they talk about xPath 2.0 functions which cannot be used in my case.

Comment: Not in `Xpath 1.0` - you'll need to match individual nodes here.

Comment: ok Jan, So I will have to accept this long xPath

Comment: Probably yes. You might be able to loop over the string programatically beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//div[contains(@id,'confirm1_container') or contains
(@id,'confirm2_container') or contains(@id,'confirm3_container') or contains
(@id,'confirm4_container')or contains
(@id,'permanentSuppressionPopUp_container')]
```

Since your above mentioned `xpath` uses the `or` expression, you will identify the first element in your list that matches one of the statements (given that you use `.FindElement()`).

So, in this case you could simplify it by using:

```
//div[contains(@id,'_container')]
```

since all your `id`s contain the `_container` part.

If you have other elements on your page that end with the `_container` part, then try this:

```
//div[contains(@id,'_container') and contains(@id,'confirm') or contains(@id,'permanentSuppressionPopUp')]
```

It's not shorter with much, but still it's easier to manage.

Comment: It is shorter than the xPath I was using.